# How to superscript a - (minus symbol) in a legend title with qpolot in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm trying to superscript a '-' straight after a subscript 4 in an axis title in ggplot2 using bquote.  I'm so close!  The following gives me everything EXCEPT a small, superscript - straight after the subscript 4:

```
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +  
ylab(bquote('Membrane available NH '[4]*'-N (  '*mu*'g' ~ resin^-1* ~ 14~day^-1*')'))
```

I've tried playing around the ^, for example:

```
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +  
ylab(bquote('Membrane available NH '[4]*^-'-N (  '*mu*'g' ~ resin^-1* ~ 14~day^-1*')'))
```

But get error messages such as:

```
Error: unexpected '^' in "qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +  
ylab(bquote('Membrane available NH '[4]*^"
```

Clearly I'm not expressing the ^ correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's the `"*^"`that is throwing the parsing error. There would need to be a symbol between those two separators. Since the '*' is the nonspace separator, it serves no purpose anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +  
  ylab(expression(Membrane~available~NH[4^~{"-"}]-N~(mu~g~resin^{-1}~14~day^{-1})))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size= 12, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
       axis.title.y= element_text(color="black", face="bold", size= 18, margin=margin(0,10,0,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite... I want "Membrane available NH(subscript 4)(superscript -) -N" BUT with a space between the 4 and the - so they are not one below the other.  The "-N" still needs to be there AFTER the superscript -  .  So yes, there are two - signs, one superscript, then a normal one.  Gosh, I hope that makes sense, it's difficult to describe in words sorry!

Comment: In your question, you said "I'm trying to superscript a '-' straight after a subscript 4". But in your comment you want two subscripts. Am I right or is it a typo?

Comment: Oh yes that may have been a typo... I think I edited it just after you read it.... definitely subscript 4 followed by a super script - followed by a normal -N.   With a small space between the subscript 4 and the superscript -  Thanks for checking! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much @aelwan.  I was able to tweak yours to get exactly what I needed (pretty sure it was just my poor explanation hindering the output!), which is:                                                      ylab(expression(Membrane~available~NH[4]^{" -"}~-N~(~mu~g~resin^{-1}~14~day^{-1})))                                                              Thank-you so much for your perseverance, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: I think it would be easier if you just take a print screen of any paper or  a book who have a figure with a label similar to yours :-)

Comment: You are definitely right.  I'm new to stack overflow, and only figured out today how to stick code in my question as actual code, not just text.  Getting there slowly....  very, very slowly.... :-P

Comment: I didn't see any spacing effect with `NH[4^~{"-"}`. (Could have put a leading space inside the quotes, though.)

Answer (score 3):

I thought what was being requested was an extra space between the subscripted 4 and the superscript minus. Using `phantom()` is one method. The length of the "space" is the same as the space needed to fit the character value (at 0.67 magnification):

```
 NH[4]^{phantom("A")~"-"}
```

This is a guess at what you might want. I took out as many quotes as possible and used `cdots` instead of juxtaposition is some places. Obviously your tastes or those of your editors) may vary:

```
qplot(uptake, data = CO2) +  
   ylab(bquote(Membrane~available~NH[4]^{phantom("__")*'-'}-
                N *(  mu %.% g [ resin]^-1 %.% ~ 14~day^-1)))
```

If it's suppose to be micrograms then use `mu*g~`